# Set Tkinter Label Text from SharedCtypes array

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter, python-multiprocessing

Ok, i have some multiprocess code and i try to monitor the value of some array in my program. I do some research but still not found any solution here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Array
import time

class Form:
    def __init__(self, timer):  
        window = Tk()
        window.wm_title('Multiprocess Monitor')

        tvar = StringVar()
        tvar.set(timer)

        ArrayStat = Label(window, textvariable = tvar)

        window.loop()

def Countdown(timer):
    while True:
        for i,v in enumerate(timer):
            timer[i] = v-1
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    timer = Array('i',[-1,-1,-1,-1])
    Ptimer = mp.Process(target = Countdown, args=(timer,))
    Ptimer.daemon = True
    Ptimer.start()

    app = Form(timer)

    Ptimer.join()
```

The normal way to print sharedctypes array is print(timer[:]). But if use this way in tvar => tvar.set(timer[:]) , my GUI didn't updating the text in label. if i use tvar.set(timer) , the label will show <&SychronizedArray bla bla bla.....> Is there any possible solution? thanks

Comment: Help...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Array
import time

class Form(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Multiprocess Monitor')
        self.ArrayStat = Label(self, text="test")
        self.ArrayStat.pack()

        self.after(10, self.update_label)

    def update_label(self):
        self.ArrayStat.configure(text=timer[:])
        self.after(10, self.update_label)

def Countdown(timer):
    while True:
        for i,v in enumerate(timer):
            timer[i] = v-1
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Form()
    timer = Array('i',[-1,-1,-1,-1])
    Ptimer = mp.Process(target = Countdown, args=(timer,))
    Ptimer.daemon = True
    Ptimer.start()

    app.mainloop()

    Ptimer.join()
```

your code as posted wouldn't even run, undeclared variables etc.
you also hadn't packed/gridded/placed your label so nothing would ever appear.
because a tkinter window cannot be serialised for passing between processes an update of the label cannot be directly called, however an `after` loop can keep checking the value of the timer variable which is shared between the two processes.
also its bad practice to call `mainloop` inside the constructor, so i have moved it out into the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your answer, explanation and correction. The that posted in my question i copy paste from some part of my real code and place it in here, and i forget some detail.. i never know about 'configure' and 'after', what keyword should i google for that two syntax?

Comment: the arguments you can pass to configure will vary depending on the widget in use, but generally any argument you pass when you create the widget (aside from the parent widget) can be passed to the `configure` function to change after widget is created. for after, see here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method